# How do I convert an image in Java as is done for Keras in Python?

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, caffe, tensorflow-lite

I have an image that I want to run in tensorflowlite. I have saved the model.tflite file and am trying to format an image to provide results for. I produced the following code:

```
private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ModelConfig.MODEL_INPUT_SIZE);
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        int[] pixels = new int[ModelConfig.INPUT_IMG_SIZE_WIDTH * ModelConfig.INPUT_IMG_SIZE_HEIGHT];
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        for (int pixel : pixels) {
            float rChannel = ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF); / 255.f ;
            float gChannel = ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF); / 255.f;
            float bChannel = ((pixel) & 0xFF); / 255.f;
            byteBuffer.putFloat(rChannel);
            byteBuffer.putFloat(gChannel);
            byteBuffer.putFloat(bChannel);
        }
}
```

However, when I put this into my model the output is unexpected. Reading into it, it appears that my Python implementation is doing some clever back-end processing that I do not know how to replicate into Java. As an example, it seems to format the data into *caffe* mode. The shape is (1, 224, 224, 3) and I'm not certain also how to replicate this for the Java model. My current Python code that works well is:

```
    img = load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
    print(img.shape)
    img = preprocess_input(img)
    return img
```

I'm unsure how, given a Bitmap object, to convert the image into the correct format for my tensorflow model. Currently the model runs on the current input, but it just produces the wrong results. I'd like it to replicate the results achieved when I use the model in Python.

Comment: what is `preprocess_input(img)` ?

Comment: It could be (because you mention Caffe) that the model expects (3, 224, 224), i.e. three planes: 50176 red float values, then green, and blue. TFlite does not have a universal definition of float ranges in input. Often, range of `0..1` is used, in which case you should divide **xChannel** values by **256.f**. But sometimes, range of `-1..1` is used, then you shoudl divide by **128.f** and substract **1.f**.